# Escape char problem while generating JavaScript page through Java code?

Tags: java, javascript

I am generating [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) pages through [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) code like:

```
FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\searcheng.html");
OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(fs);
out.write("<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>");
out.write("var str=new String('C:\\Documents and  Settings\\prajakta\\Desktop\\substr.html');");
out.write("var beg=str.lastIndexOf('\\');");//double' \' **Problem Stmt**
```

And so on.

The problem is when searcheng.html is created it contains

```
var beg=str.lastIndexOf('\');//single '/'
```

which creates a problem in finding index of '\'.
How should I write this problem so that it will contain double "\"?

Similarly how should I write a statement

```
out.write("document.write('< a href='str'> '+str.slice(beg+1,end)+' </a>');");
```

so that it will create statement in JavaScript as

```
document.write('< a href=" 'str' ">  '+str.slice(beg+1,end)+'  </a>');
```

and the link will go to page whose address is stored in `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out.write("var beg=str.lastIndexOf('\\\\');");
```

should do the trick. Double for Java, double again for JavaScript...

Comment: similarly  how should i write a statement 
out.write(" document.write('<a href='str'>  '+str.slice(beg+1,end)+'  </a>');");

so that it will create statement in javascript
document.write("<a href=' "+str+" '>  "+str.slice(beg+1,end)+"  </a>"); 
and the link will go to page whose address is stored in str

Comment: out.write(" document.write(\"<a href='str'> '+str.slice(beg+1,end)+' </a>\");");

Answer (score 1):

In Java string literals the backslash character has a special meaning as a escape character. If you want to represent the backslash character itself you will need to escape it with itself.

That's why the Java String literal `"\\"` represents a String with one letter, that letter being a backslash.

If you want to represent a String with two backslashes you will need to escape both in your literal: `"\\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    out.write("var beg=str.lastIndexOf('\\\\\\');");
```

The point is that '\' is the escape character in Java, so to have 1, you must write 2. To have 2, you must write 4.